# Bootstrap modal backdrop remains after closing modal

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I'm just following the w3school tutorial 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp
to add a modal in my html page.

There is no problem in displaying the modal. But when I close the modal, the screen greyed out and inaccessible for a few seconds. After that, the screen is responsive again. And it happens only for the first time when my page is launched.

I have tried following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="false">Close</button>
```

But it does not remove the grey out. I have no idea how to fixed it. Please help me! Thanks in advance!

Edited:
This is the section that can be clicked:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tt-modal">
    <div id="tt">
        <div class="desc_hidden">
             <div class="title"> Product name </div>
             <div class="subtitle"> Description </div>
             <div class="view">VIEW PROJECT</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

So, the following modal will be display after clicking above section:

```
<div id="tt-modal" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="false">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <!-- some information here -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="false">Close</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
$('#your-modal-id').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Good Luck.

I tested your modal,it worked with out any problem. just there were tiny problems there,you don't need define `data-backdrop="false"` attribute in header's and footer's button,instead set this attribute for trigger modal button.

Comment: would you please place your modal her.